# Way to simulate class categorization in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Some programming languages have the feature of adding "Categories" to classes (for example Objective-C), this means, adding new functionality to a class without subclassing.

I really find it useful, but I can't imagine a way of simulating this feature in Java.

So the question is:

How would look an elegant pattern to simulate class categories in Java? What I'm really looking for is achieving the same effect rather of making it the same way.

Comment: short answer: none, other than subclassing or than alternatively just provide Util classes

Comment: I'm not talking about making it exactly the same way but achieving the same effect.

Comment: "the java way" is either subclassing it or using composition. the procedural way is using and Utils class, for instance, for class C, create a CUtils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inter-type declaration feature](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html) of [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to add functionality to existing classes.

Comment: @Juan Alberto López Cavallotti, AspectJ is one of popular libraries that perform byte code modification. This is what I actually tried to say...

Comment: @AlexR first of all AspectJ is a seamless aspect-oriented extension to the Java programming language. It has full featured compiler for Java and AspectJ code. It also of course could modify existing classes, but such feature is rather secondary. Calling AspectJ a bytecode modification library is the same as calling Java compiler a bytecode generation framework.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you'll probably be able to do this via a combination of Interface Injection (adding new `interface`s to existing classes) and Default Methods (providing default implementations for `interface` methods).

Comment: I didn't know about this new feature for java 8, +1 for that :) But I'm really looking for a pattern to use with current java.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways.

You can use Dynamic proxy. This feature means that JVM "implements" interface for you at runtime providing ability to implement callback method where you can call "real" implementation.

Other way is byte code engineering. But IMHO the first way is easier.

Comment: I'm really looking for a design pattern rather than modifying the bytecode, but thanks anyway.